# Regex - Don't match nulls after words

Tags: regex, plsql

I'm splitting a string on pipes (|) and the regex `[^|]*` is working fine when there are missing fields, but it's matching null characters after words:

`GARBAGE|||GA|30604`
yields matches

`GARBAGE, null, null, null, GA, null, 30604, null`

I've also tried `[^|]+` which yields matches

`GARBAGE, GA, 30604`

EDIT: What I want is `GARBAGE, null, null, GA, 30604`. And `||||` would yield matches `null, null, null, null, null`.

I'm referencing matches by index, so how can I fix the regex so it matches field by field, including nulls if there is no other data in the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how split works. You should use a split type function.
There is always a *bias* split uses.

Your case is simple in that it splits on a single character, in normal cases a regex is not needed.
And in this case, using a regex, the bias cannot be achieved without lookahead/lookbehind.

```
 # (?:^|(?<=\|))([^|]*)(?=\||$)

 (?:
      ^                     # BOS
   |                      # or
      (?<= \| )             # Pipe behind
 )
 ( [^|]* )             # (1), Optional non-pipe chars
 (?=
      \|                    # Pipe ahead
   |                      # or
      $                     #  EOS
 )
```

Comment: This works perfectly at rubular.com, but PL/SQL is matching nothing but nulls with `v_fullname := REGEXP_SUBSTR(input_line, v_regex, 1, 2);`. Do you have any insight as to why this might be?

Comment: @benjsigmon - Sorry, I don't know pl/sql. But, looking at the regex, you don't need the capture group. And for a test you could put the escaped pipe into a stand-alone class. Also, make sure the v_regex string is proper. It should be the raw regex when printed. `(?:^|(?<=[|]))[^|]*(?=[|]|$)`

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly what you want, perhaps you could turn it into rows and work with it that way:

```
select nvl(regexp_substr( str, '([^|]*)\|{0,1}', 1, level, 'i', 1 ), 'null') part
from ( select 'GARBAGE|||GA|30604' str from dual )
connect by level <= regexp_count( str, '\|' ) + 1;
```

[image]

Specify which row (field) by adding a where clause where level equals the row (field) you want:

```
select nvl(regexp_substr( str, '([^|]*)\|{0,1}', 1, level, 'i', 1 ), 'null') part
from ( select 'GARBAGE|||GA|30604' str from dual )
where level = 4
connect by level <= regexp_count( str, '\|' ) + 1;
```

[image]