# Use SQL to extract characters with multiple back slashes

Tags: sql, string

I have a string:

```
 \_AAA\DDDD\09090\longtest
```

How can I extract just the string  `09090`?
There will be many strings like these and I would like to extract the string between the 3rd and fourth back slash.

Comment: 3 questions: Is the text between each set of \ the same length or variable lengths?  is the 4th \ always the last one? and lastly what RDBMS?  all SQL is not the same.

Comment: What's your RDBMS? Do you want SQL-only solution, or can you, let's say, C#?

Answer (score 0):

I'll bite.  Here's an Oracle solution that grabs what's in the 3rd field:

```
select regexp_substr('\_AAA\DDDD\09090\longtest', '[^\]+', 1, 3) from dual;
```

Technically it grabs the 3rd match of a set of characters that do not match a backslash.

I just realized it does not allow for a null field though.

This works:

```
select nvl(regexp_substr( str, '([^\\]*)\\{0,1}', 1, level, 'i', 1 ), 'null') part
from ( select '\_AAA\DDDD\09090\longtest' str from dual )
where level = 4
connect by level <= regexp_count( str, '\' ) + 1;
```

From here:

[Regex - Don't match nulls after words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418590/regex-dont-match-nulls-after-words/24540508#24540508)

Answer (score 0):

A simple (though not necessarily efficient) solution for SQL Server is:

```
SELECT Substring(text, first, second - first) 
FROM   (SELECT text, 
               Charindex('\', text, Charindex('\', text, Charindex('\', text)+1) 
               +1) 
               + 1                       first, 
               Charindex('\', text, Charindex('\', text, Charindex('\', text, 
                                    Charindex 
                                    ('\', 
                                    text)+1)+1) 
                                    + 1) second 
        FROM   table1)T
```

See a working example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e010/12)

---

**EDIT**

A better answer uses a recursive query.

Try something like this:

```
WITH A 
     AS (SELECT CAST(0 AS BIGINT)     AS idx1, 
                CHARINDEX('\', TEXT) idx2, 
                TEXT, 
                0                     AS rn 
         FROM   TABLE1 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT CAST(IDX2 + 1 AS BIGINT), 
                CHARINDEX('\', TEXT, IDX2 + 1), 
                TEXT, 
                RN + 1 
         FROM   A 
         WHERE  IDX2 > 0) 
SELECT SUBSTRING(TEXT, IDX1, IDX2 - IDX1) 
FROM   A 
WHERE  RN = 3
```

It is much better since you can easily adapt it to extract any part of the string, not just the third.

See a working example of this on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e010/25)